# Computing inverse of modified matrix using Sherman-Morrison formula

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following implementation that takes in symmetric matrix W and returns matrix C

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import time

W = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

A = W.clone()    
[n_node, _] = A.shape
nI = n_node * torch.eye(n_node)

# -- method 1
C = torch.empty(n_node, n_node)   

for i in range(n_node):
    for j in range(i, n_node):
        B = A.clone()
        B[i, j] = B[j, i] = 0
        C[i, j] = C[j, i] = torch.inverse(nI - B)[i, j]
```

As you can see, I have a matrix `nI - B` and change one element at each loop and compute its inverse. Im trying to use [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9875/computing-inverse-matrix-when-an-element-changes) to enhance the performance of the code. Here is my implementation:

```
# -- method 2
c = torch.empty(n_node, n_node)

inv_nI_A = torch.inverse(nI - A)
b = torch.div(A, 1 + torch.einsum('ij,ij->ij', A, inv_nI_A))
inv_nI_A_ = inv_nI_A.unsqueeze(1)

for i in range(n_node):
    for j in range(i, n_node):
        c[i, j] = c[j, i] = (inv_nI_A - b[i, j] * torch.matmul(inv_nI_A_[:, :, i], inv_nI_A_[j, :, :]))[i, j]
```

I was wondering if I can do further enhancements on my implementation. Thanks!

PS: W is not necessarily a sparse matrix.

Comment: Based on the Sherman-Morrison formula, it seems that further mathematical simplifications can be done to throw away for-loops completely (and replace them with implicit vectorized PyTorch operations). BTW, your 'method 1' code does not incorporate all the improvements in the code of my previous review. E.g., copying the entire matrix using A.clone() in each loop might be more readable but it is really inefficient when only two elements need to be changed.

Comment: @GZ0 1. It isn't immediately clear to me how to get rid of the final loop. 2. Thanks for bringing the 'A.clone()' part to my attention. 3. I forgot to mark your answer as accepted, thanks for the review again!

Comment: Inside each loop only one element needs to be calculated. Based on the Sherman-Morrison formula, it is possble to do just that rather than computing the entire matrix inverse for accessing the element.